# Font awesome icons in buefy

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome, buefy

I'm trying to switch my project from **bulma + jQuery** to **buefy**. I load **buefy**, **vue** and **font awesome** from a cdn. **(buefy@0.6.7, vue@2.5.17, font awesome 5.2.0)**. The main problem I have with icons. My project uses font awesome icons. And default buefy iconPack is material design. It must support font awesome. I've tried to change the default icon pack, but that does nothing:

```
Vue.use(Buefy.default, {
    defaultIconPack: 'fas',
});
```

the same nothing:

```
Vue.use(Buefy, {
    defaultIconPack: 'fas',
});
```

So I need to point the iconpack explicitly for every icon.

The second problem is that even in this case buefy adds `fa-lg` that I don't need at all. For example for b-tab-item component

```
<b-tab-item label="Similarity" icon="search" icon-pack="fas"></b-tab-item>
```

It renders:

```
<i class="fas fa fa-search fa-lg"></i>
```

Is it possible to change this buefy behaviour?

Answer (score 16):

to anyone that may still struggle with this. my problems was solved by using this in my `main.js`:

```
import Buefy from 'buefy'
import 'buefy/dist/buefy.css'

import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
// internal icons
import { fas } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome";

library.add(fas);
Vue.component('vue-fontawesome', FontAwesomeIcon);


Vue.use(Buefy, {
  defaultIconComponent: "vue-fontawesome",
  defaultIconPack: "fas",
  customIconPacks: {
    fas: {
      sizes: {
        default: "lg",
        "is-small": "1x",
        "is-medium": "2x",
        "is-large": "3x"
      },
      iconPrefix: ""
    }
  }
});
```

make sure to install all the dependencies using `npm`:

```
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/vue-fontawesome
```

then you can use it in your components as follows:

```
<b-icon
  pack="fas"
  icon="user"
  size="is-large"
  type="is-success"></b-icon>
```

Answer (score 6):

This is working code for me in buefy

**in main.js**

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'

library.add(fas)
Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
Vue.use(Buefy, { defaultIconPack: 'fas' })
```

and in **index.html**

place in head tag

```
<link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css"
      integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
```

make sure first off you add the [fortawesome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome) npm package

Answer (score 3):

If you run:

```
yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

And then import:

```
import '../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js'
```

It should then work. Importing from a CDN doesn't seem to work.

Comment: this should be accepted answer, as it doesn't force user to create an additional layer of abstraction for fontawesome icons like creating separate/dedicated `font-awesome-icon` component!

Answer (score 2):

Further to original answer.  This is working code for me using a CDN:

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Buefy from 'buefy';
import 'buefy/dist/buefy.css'

Vue.use(Buefy, {
  defaultIconPack: 'fas'
});

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

template

```
<template>

  <div class="container">
    <b-tabs
      is-boxed>
        <b-tab-item label="Search" icon="search"></b-tab-item>
        <b-tab-item label="Music" icon="music"></b-tab-item>
        <b-tab-item label="Videos" icon="video"></b-tab-item>
    </b-tabs>
  </div>
</template>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>buefy-test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but buefy-test doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```